# Trying to lock screen to portrait. Intel XDK 3922

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, cordova

Trying to lock screen to portrait on Android, iOS, windows.

I tried using cordova-plugin-screen-orientation but my code below is not working.

```
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready", onDeviceReady, false);               

function onDeviceReady() {
   intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation('portrait');  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go into the build settings and look for "Orientation". Click on the white box next to it and click "Portrait". Repeat on all platforms' build settings, with no code required.

I hope this helped!